# Jquery Onload Function stopped for loop, passing for loop x inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop, filereader

I'm passing image files from XMLHttpRequest to this function **readfiles(files)** by using **dataTransfer**

what i'm trying to do is to preview the images and the image file names at the same time and in one line code inside the **reader.onload()** function.

and because there will be more than 1 file passed to the function, i threw them into a for loop

the problem is when i try to preview the images by **readDataURL** it's ok but the file names cannot be previewed i think because the **reader.onload()** function stopped the for loop from looping trough the image files.

**Here's my code**

```
function readfiles(files) {

    var x;

    for(x = 0; x < files.length; x = x + 1) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[x]);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.result);
            console.log(files[x].name);
        }   

    }
}
```

have been searching for solution about 5 hours now, any help!

Comment: What are you getting in your console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ROX's answer is not right.  In his case, you will see that it will output the same file name 4 times.  What you need is a closure which will essentially keep the right context on each iteration. You can achieve this as follows. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cy03fc8x/.

```
function readfiles(files) {
    for(x = 0; x < files.length; x = x + 1) {
        var file = files[x];
        (function(file){   //this is a closure which we use to ensure each iteration has the right version of the variable 'file'
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.result);
                console.log(file.name);
            }
        })(file);          //on each iteration, pass in the current file to the closure so that it can be used within

    }
}
```

Comment: it worked! .. i can't find a way to thank you, i really appreciate your help .. you saved me, thanks alot!

Comment: Yes you are right, the closure is needed here, I've also updated my answer to keep it correct, and also **`+1`** :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `onload` will run later, at that moment, the `x` is one more than your number of files. For example if you have 4 files, the `x` will be `5` when the `onload` executes.

So keep a reference to your current file:

```
function readfiles(files) {
    for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x = x + 1) {
        // keep reference to current file on iteration
        var file = files[x];

        // create closure and execute it
        (function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                console.log(file.name);
            }
        }(file)); // pass the `file` to the function
    }
}
```

Comment: I kept the variable name outside the onload function (copied and pasted your code) and the results giving me the same file name ex. 4 times! like 1.jpg | 1.jpg | 1.jpg .. etc! Why is this happening?